# isEnabled() with Adapter Android

Tags: android, listview, isenabled

I am using below code to disable `ListView` item. Now, the problem is that after disabling one item, if user clicks on another item, It disables present item but removes last item from disabling.
How to prevent this problem ?

```
    int pos;
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist, R.layout.topicwisequestion, new String[] { "option" }, new int[] { R.id.option }) {

                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position != 0) {
                        if (position == pos) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            };

            lvTWOptions.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvTWOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    pos = position;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the list of disabled  items and see if that item is present in the list in isEnabled.

As below:

```
ArrayList<Integer> pos=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist, R.layout.topicwisequestion, new String[] { "option" }, new int[] { R.id.option }) {

                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position != 0) {
                        if (pos.contains(position)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            };

            lvTWOptions.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvTWOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    pos.add(position);
                }
            });
```